# How to truncate number 3 decimals

Tags: php, numbers

I would like to truncate numbers at 3 decimals with php :

```
3.236665   3.236
3.236111   3.236
```

Thanks

Comment: `round(3.236665, 3) === 3.237`.

Comment: wrong, I dont want to round the number but to truncate it

Comment: Try this man, $value = explode('.',$value*1000)[0] / 1000;
Just parse to float if you want it to be float.

Comment: And BTW, this is not a duplicate question as suggested by @Rizier123. Definitely a separate case. Perhaps understand the case before taking action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To truncate a number up to `p` decimals, multiply the number by p-th power of 10, truncate the fraction by casting to integer, then divide the result by p-th power of 10.

The following truncates `$n` up to the 3rd decimal:

```
intval($n * 1e3) / 1e3;
```

Comment: I would like to say this solution is mostly accurate but there exceptions where the result is wrong. Example : if $n = 1.005, int ($n * 1e3) = 1004 and not 1005 due to float approximation